# Pushing values to an object using unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am trying to push some properties and values to a Firebase object, using the Unique ID and cannot figure out how to do this. The object tree looks like this:

[image: Firebase Object]

I am referencing the `projects` object using `var Projects = DB.child('projects');`, `DB` being my Firebase database variable. When I try and access the object by the unique ID: `Projects['-K1VohAnRvGfdtV6lyaH']`, the console tells me that the object is undefined. What am I missing here?

Comment: try quotation marks around the key like so
Projects["-K1VohAnRvGfdtV6lyaH"]

Comment: @harmonickey I'm so sorry, I had quotes around the unique ID and did not use them when posting my question. That does not work.

Comment: have you looked at the object in the debugger, and ensure the properties exist?  This will work if the properties exist and the key is spelled correctly.

Comment: The property does not exist and this is something that is confusing me. I believe it has to do with the way Firebase works. Here is what `console.dir(Projects);` shows: https://www.dropbox.com/s/if85knr5emd1edc/Screenshot%202015-10-26%2010.22.07.png?dl=0

Comment: I am not familiar with Firebase, but my guess is you need to use an include on the data call to let it know to include the layer of data your looking for.  At least that how most other ORMs work.

Comment: Question and something to try.
What did you reference for your DB object?  
Try DB.child('projectr/projects') then query Projects in the same way.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a lot easier than I was trying to make it. I just had to use the child method and post the data that way. Here is my code:

```
var projectId = $('table').attr('id');
    projectId = projectId.replace('table', '');
    var path = Projects.child(projectId).child('items');

    path.push({
        item_vendor: vendor,
        item_description: description,
        item_cost: cost
});
```

Each table has the unique ID of the project that it is displaying, so I grabbed the unique ID from there. Then I just had to append the child locations to the `path` to be able to push the data where it needed to go.

p.s. The second child item is a property I am adding on the fly. I may could combine `projectId` and `'items'` and only use one `child()` method, but it works for now.

Thanks for all of the help guys.